# Why does apt-get exit without an error during Dockerfile build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apt-get

For some reason, I've been unable to complete a `docker build` without the process stopping and no error being provided. I've googled around, and no-one appears to have the same issue.

The first (and salient) part of the Dockerfile config I'm using:

```
FROM java:8-jre

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install needed packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    cron
```

The command I'm using to execute the build (build.cmd):

```
@ECHO OFF

docker --debug --log-level debug build . ^
    --build-arg http_proxy=%http_proxy% ^
    --build-arg https_proxy=%https_proxy% ^
    --build-arg no_proxy=%no_proxy% ^
    --tag "bravura/jfrog-mission-control:latest" ^
    %*
```

The result of running it:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  133.9MB
Step 1/7 : FROM java:8-jre
 ---> e44d62cf8862
Step 2/7 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f30e6ab20920
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 677bd445e48c
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [508 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2373 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [17.6 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages [1150 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9065 kB]
Fetched 11.3 MB in 6s (1829 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Here's the big one: Running the same set of commands in a shell brought up by running `docker run -it --rm java:8-jre /bin/bash` works perfectly fine.

The other interesting bit: Concatenating the two commands together (with &&) defers the exit to the end of both executions. In fact, no errors are actually produced, so appending additional commands to the end works just fine (e.g. `apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && echo "Done!"`)

Any help even identifying where the issue could be reported would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** As is the way with these things, I thought to look in the service logs as soon as I posted this. Found the following tidbits that might point me in the right direction:

```
[13:50:31.818][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] error copying response body from Docker:  unexpected EOF
[13:50:31.818][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] error closing response body from Docker:  unexpected EOF
```

Still no real idea what it means, however. Might just be another symptom rather than a cause.

**Update:** Just ran the build again to double-check the submitted responses, and without changes to my Dockerfile, everything is now working beautifully. One possible option is that the issue was silently fixed in the last update (which I installed today). I don't really have time to revert and re-test, so this is it until I run into the issue again, or someone else gets the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

unexpected EOF (end of file). it seems you forgot the "\" at the end of your RUN command.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron && echo "Done!" \
```

or

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cron && \
    echo "Done!" \
```

Comment: That just causes my build to fail as it appends my next command directly to that one, ending up with `RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get install ...etc`

Answer (score 0):

@Tzrlk are you working behind the corporate proxy? Try running this command directly in your terminal first and then use the docker build command and see.

```
export http_proxy=http://your proxy here:port here
export https_proxy=http://your proxy here:port here
```

Comment: Yup, and it's a massive pain, but I've definitely got all my proxy settings in both windows and the shell set up correctly. There's no issue with connectivity, finishing a RUN command with apt-get in it just causes a hard exit.